# Memory Allocation Java Anomaly

Tags: java, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm learning Java from a book called "Java 2: The Complete Reference".

The output according to the book is:
Total memory is: 1048568
**Initial free memory: 751392
Free memory after garbage collection: 841424**
Free memory after allocation: 824000
Memory used by allocation: 17424
Free memory after collecting discarded Integers: 842640

My output is:
Total memory is : 121634816
**Initial free memory : 120142456
Free memory after garbage collection : 7677000**
Free memory after allocation : 7635040
Memory used by allocation : 41960
Free memory after collecting discarded integers : 7677960

My problem is the above boldly mentioned part. The "initial free memory" mentioned in the output of the book is less than "free memory after garbage collection" whereas in my output "initial free memory" is way more than that of "free memory after garbage collection".

```
class MemoryDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long mem1, mem2;
        Integer someInts[] = new Integer[1000];

        System.out.println("Total memory is : " + r.totalMemory());

        mem1 = r.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Initial free memory : " + mem1);

        r.gc();
        mem1 = r.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Free memory after garbage collection : " + mem1);

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            someInts[i] = new Integer(i);

        mem2 = r.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Free memory after allocation : " + mem2);

        System.out.println("Memory used by allocation : " + (mem1 - mem2));

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            someInts[i] = null;

        r.gc();
        mem2 = r.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Free memory after collecting discarded integers :" + mem2);
    }
}
```

I need explanation for this bit and I'm attaching a link for downloading the book in the description. The code is on 406 page of book.
http://iiti.ac.in/people/~tanimad/JavaTheCompleteReference.pdf

Comment: The book clearly states "Sample output from this program is shown here (of course, your actual results may vary):"

Comment: Have you used the same JVM version like the one used in the book? The JVM evolves and garbage collector and memory management are two points the JVM have evolved a lot in the last years. Also the memory usage of the example is way too low. You are more measuring the core ram usage of the JVM, not of the program. Also you can't compare memory usage of 32bit and 64bit JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory size of a Java Virtual Machine is not a fixed quantity.  You can set it at JVM startup.  The default setting may vary from implementation to implementation and from version to version.  The default may well depend on the size of the actual computer memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error or a mistake. Your computer has more memory than the author of the books computer had at the the time the book was written.

Comment: My doubt is why is my "free memory after garbage collection" less than "initial free memory" whereas in the book, it is different.

Comment: There has never been a way to force garbage collection; calling `gc()` is advisory, the jvm doesn't guarantee anything from that call.